# In WebView,the js function window.innerHeight just return 0?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am developing a web app in Android, and I use a WebView to play some pages. The following is my html code and I write a js function to get the height of my browser screen height.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    alert(window.innerHeight);
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="background:black;">
</body>
</html>
```

I test the above code in my Defy 480*800 mobile device and in the WebView, it just returns 0 and sometimes other number. But in browser, it works right.

So I wonder if there is something I should know to get the available screen height in WebView?

---

update: 2012.3.13

Thanks Demonick, I follow your suggestion and find the lazyload.js,I use the setTimeout to make a poll to get the window's height.

Hope it helps others.

```
<script>
//poll numbers
var pollCount=0;

//get the window Height
var pollWindowHeight=function(){
    //poll the window innerHeight 10s
    if(window.innerHeight==0){
        pollCount+=1;

        if(pollCount<200)   {
            setTimeout(pollWindowHeight,50);
        }else{
            //just stop polling or you can do some others
        }
    }else{
        //use the window.innerHeight to do something...
    }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",pollWindowHeight, false);
</script>
```

Reference: https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the `window.innerHeight` function in `document.onready` or later instead, because the height might have not been initialized on `onload` yet.